# Cannot find my question.

Tags: support

Yesterday, I posted a question in math.stackexchange.com and now I can't find it. The title included 'nonempty finite subset'. I clicked my icon and used ^F in my browser to find that string but could not find it. How do I find it? Can you help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085929/460967 good luck.

Comment: I found the same post at the top of your New Posts list on your Profile tab Math.SE page.  Note that by default Math.SE shows you your Activity tab, but you can easily switch from one to the other.

Comment: The question you are looking for appears to be the first here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/525457/stf91?tab=questions

Answer (score 7):

First, go to your profile and hit main user

[image]

Now, hit activity

[image]

Now, go to questions

[image]

Here it is

[image]

Comment: I hate it when I post an answer to the wrong question (or to the main site instead of the meta site), too... thanks for doing all of this.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, it is an honor to get appreciation for a $330$k rep

Comment: That just means I’ve been around a long time (internet-wise) and haven’t moved on. Kind of like the “25 year member” certificate I recently got from the MAA, which I took to mean “Hey, you’re old and you keep giving us money, so thank you!”

Comment: I went to my profile but I didn't see any 'Main user' button or link. Where is it?

Comment: Sorry, I now saw the 'main user' button and I reached the 'Questions' list but my question is not there!

Comment: @stf91 What do you mean?? Try following the steps again

Comment: @stf91:  Are you sure that you are logged in?

Comment: I think you can go directly from Profile to Activity without any intermediate steps, when you're on mathse. Think of the top left as tabs, and you can go back and forth between Profile and Activity, stf91.

Comment: Nice work, SomeGuy!!